# How do I make a <pre> horizontally scroll and not overflow when inside a non-fixed table cell?

Tags: css, pre

I have this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <pre style="overflow: scroll;">
                    (really long lines of text)
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7n8w02f/

In my scenario, I have these considerations:

- The `<table>` cannot have `table-layout: fixed` (in my real-world page the `<table>` has `width: 100%` but in the JSFiddle it's `width: 600px`).
- The width of the `<td>` varies.
- No word-wrapping in the `<pre>` and whitespace must be preserved.
- The `<pre>` needs to fill the width of the `<td>`.
- The text within the `<pre>` must not overflow or overspill outside the visual bounds of the `<pre>` (which would be the same as the `<td>`, disregarding padding and margins), so tThe `<pre>` must scroll horizontally if its text is wider than the `<td>`.

However there doesn't seem to be any way to do this!

All solutions I've seen so far place a few limitations on the document and stylesheet:

- Use `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>`.
- Set an absolute width on the `<pre>` with `overflow: scroll` (or `overflow-x: scroll`), e.g. `width: 500px` but not `width: 100%` (which doesn't work).
- I've varied all of the `white-space`, `word-wrap`, `overflow`, and `overflow-x`  CSS properties to no effect.

Comment: the trick is to have something that gives a limit to the width but based on your requirement you cannot do it.

Comment: and why you cannot use `table-layout:fixed` which seems to be the trivial fix for your issue?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The table's columns have unpredictable content that must be shown using variable-width columns. I cannot set widths on the columns beforehand or let the browser infer width from the first table row.

Comment: If the pre's content must scroll within the td, the pre's content cannot be used to determine the dimensions of the td. So how are the dimensions of the td that contains the pre to be determined?

Comment: @Alohci The width of the `<td>` would be defined by other, non-`<pre>` content in the same column in other rows by the automatic table layout algorithm defined in CSS - the same as if the `<td>` was populated entirely with `<div style="width: 100%;">`.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood the requirements correctly, you can put the pre element in as an absolute positioned box inside a relatively positioned td element. Like this.

```css
table {
  border: 1px outset #999;
  
  width: 600px;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px inset #999;
}
.pre-container {
  position: relative;
}

pre {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
    <td class="pre-container">
      <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nisl nisi, volutpat eget tempus vitae, iaculis non magna. Phasellus efficitur ante ipsum, eget posuere diam dapibus at. Sed vel leo sit amet sapien feugiat congue. Nunc lorem velit, bibendum eu dignissim eu, efficitur ultrices metus. Suspendisse accumsan dolor ut tortor maximus, et volutpat velit eleifend. Donec commodo malesuada auctor. Proin cursus euismod porttitor. Duis posuere id ex sollicitudin vestibulum. Sed nisi odio, imperdiet ac mollis sit amet, luctus id odio. Fusce laoreet libero non nunc ornare, ac pharetra mi rutrum. Quisque rhoncus vehicula lorem, sit amet consequat neque. Nullam sodales ligula ac orci tincidunt semper. In efficitur magna ut viverra eleifend.

Donec luctus purus nunc, id suscipit nisi dignissim quis. Vivamus vel ligula massa. Proin nec scelerisque ligula. Mauris tristique metus enim. Quisque blandit nunc at nunc maximus laoreet. Nunc nisl sapien, lacinia vitae risus vitae, rutrum interdum nibh. Nunc a sem sem. Ut leo lectus, tempus a sagittis eu, mattis eu orci. Pellentesque dignissim mi diam, et sollicitudin leo facilisis pretium. Ut et tempor dolor. Suspendisse laoreet odio elit, at ultricies justo pellentesque quis. Vestibulum et diam ac ipsum laoreet maximus ac eu elit. Integer et elementum urna.

Curabitur sagittis tortor eu justo laoreet, nec pharetra massa congue. Duis hendrerit venenatis diam, non suscipit arcu. Quisque aliquam pretium mauris, ac cursus risus eleifend nec. Nulla non sem ac mi auctor tempus in nec velit. In cursus vel ex nec pellentesque. Etiam consequat eget libero nec dictum. Vestibulum viverra neque vel urna semper vehicula. Praesent ac felis sollicitudin, convallis nisi vel, consequat lorem. Morbi eu elit at enim tempor maximus vel ut magna. Integer dignissim convallis consequat.

Fusce aliquam libero in sem volutpat rhoncus. Suspendisse vulputate interdum nibh non efficitur. Morbi massa dolor, egestas a sodales a, rhoncus quis turpis. Vivamus velit erat, rutrum vitae lectus sed, luctus vulputate augue. Aenean elementum tortor eros, eget hendrerit purus viverra eget. Praesent ultricies pulvinar gravida. Nullam pulvinar feugiat laoreet. Fusce sit amet est facilisis, mattis erat a, consectetur felis. Sed eleifend faucibus felis, eget auctor nunc egestas suscipit. Sed in lobortis mi. Phasellus aliquet elit at tristique ullamcorper. Nullam augue eros, ornare et nisl ac, tempor volutpat sem. Praesent in felis vehicula, imperdiet mi eget, laoreet diam.

Praesent at tellus diam. Fusce vulputate, ipsum non vulputate vehicula, elit sem viverra mi, eu suscipit arcu leo et mi. Curabitur nec dolor ultrices, bibendum eros hendrerit, gravida ex. Donec ac porttitor erat. Nullam gravida egestas mi, vel tristique ante suscipit nec. Nullam ut ante rhoncus nisi varius feugiat. Pellentesque aliquet tincidunt ante vitae sollicitudin.</pre>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```